# How to use Paging 3 library with RxJava 3 on Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, rx-java, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

At Jetpack Compose documentation, it says that use `collectAsLazyPagingItems()` to get `LazyPagingItems`, and pass to LazyColumn's items.

The problem is; `collectAsLazyPagingItems()` function only works in Kotlin Flows, and it seems to only way to create `LazyPagingItems` type variable according to documentation [(LazyPagingItems Documentation)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItems).

Is there any way to use RxJava instead of Flow to use Paging library on Jetpack Compose?